# ADF - parametrized linked service - concat URL with secret and parameter

Tags: azure-data-factory

I need to create a REST parametrized linked service whose URL should be concatenated from base URL read from key vault and a value coming from linked service parameter.

E.g. https://myurl.com?count=100, where:

- **https://myurl.com** should be read from key vault (as it is different from one environment to another)
- **?count=100** should be provided as parameter to the linked service (as it needs to be predetermined at the pipeline level).

Comment: can't you use the global parameter to handle the base url for different environments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **linked service parameter** for the base url of the REST linked service like below.

[image]

In the REST dataset, create two parameters for the base url and relative url like below.

[image]

Give these to the Base url(linked service parameter) and relative url.

[image]

If you want to hardcode the secret, you can use global parameter as suggested by @

[Ashwin Mohan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8910532/ashwin-mohan) in comments.

Store the secret in a global parameter and give that parameter to the base URL like below. Also give your relative URL here.

[image]

Or if you want to get the base url secret dynamically without hardcoding, use **web activity** to get the secret from key vault and give it to the dataset parameter.

[image]

Go through this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/how-to-use-azure-key-vault-secrets-pipeline-activities) for the step-by-step process of retrieving key vault using web activity.